# When attempting to enable Multilingual app toolkit on a project, nothing happens

Tags: c#, .net, multilingual, multilingual-app-toolkit

When I try to enable the Mulitlingual app toolkit on a C# project, I get an error such as the following and nothing more happens:

> Project 'project name' was not enabled - the project's source culture could not be determined.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add a line like this to your assemblyinfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```

The indicated language is the one that the application currently uses (i.e usually hardcoded texts, before translation)

Answer (score 16):

For a .Net Standard project, edit the csproj file to add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 15):

In Visual Studio 2017 
=> Projects=>Properties=>Package=>Assembly nutral language=>English(...)=>Save 
Then 
Select Project in Solution Explorer=>Tools=>Multilingual App Toolkit =>Enable Selection
[image]

### Update: VS2019

VS2019 has a lot of changes in UI, so to find Assembly Neutral Language Option you can try below solution.

Right Click on Project => Got To Properties => Search button "Assembly Information" => Neutral Language => Select English => Save. And then rest of the process is same 
Select Project => Tools=> Multilingual App=> Enable Selection
[image]

Comment: Is still a valid solution when using VS 2019.

Answer (score 6):

Another method:

- Open project properties
- Select Application
- Click the ASSEMBLY INFOMATION button
- At the bottom, select a NEUTRAL LANGUAGE

Also in the OUTPUT panel in the SHOW OUTPUT FROM: dropdown, select MULTILINGUAL APP TOOLKIT.

Make sure you have at least one resource file!